# get facebook page feed as json with jquery

Tags: jquery, facebook-graph-api, jsonp

I have been trying to get facebook page feed from json data with jquery. so far I have been able to get page details with my method but when I try to get page's feed it gives me an error and in the console it says "syntax error: invalid label". this is my code.....

```
    $.getJSON("https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=237173582992285&format=json&callback=?", function(results){
    console.log(results);
});
```

I also have created a jsfiddle with the whole code. check it out if required -> http://jsfiddle.net/yZn7N/.
I can see all the json data if I go to the specified link and they do get fetched and I'm not sure what's causing the invalid label error. Any kind of help fixing it or explanation of why this is happening will be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use the Facebook Graph API for this to happen.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#feed

Your call should change to:

https://graph.facebook.com/237173582992285/feed?access_token=YOUR-TOKEN-GOES-HERE

You can try use this test page and try to familiarize with the graph api.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=237173582992285%2Ffeed

EDIT:

You can also get the Wall from the page in several formats.

JSON
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=237173582992285

ATOM
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=atom10&id=237173582992285

RSS
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=237173582992285

Comment: I have seen in some blogs that access token is required but isn't there any way to do it without the access token? I mean I can pull page's info without the access token so why not the feed? probably it's a silly question lol. 
thanks for your reply.

Comment: Sure, there's a way, using the RSS Feed, just specify JSON as your desired output format and you're ready to go! I've edited my post.

Comment: I have already put json as my requested format, you'll see it if you look closely to the given url. The issue here is I'm trying to get json data and as I've told you I can see all the json data if I go to the given link (I'll be glad if you have a look for yourself) as well ass rss and atom feed but when I try to pull it from my localhost with a jquery get json call or ajax call it fails and gives me the error saying "invalid label error" in my console. 
I hope I made my problem a but more clear in here.

Comment: OK, I've checked the request/response with JQuery and I have bad news. You need to have the &callback=? part in your request because you are making a cross domain request. This involves JSONP and there's no way of getting rid of it.  The error that you are receiving is because the answer sent by facebook is not in JSONP format. You need to wrap the Facebook call by implementing a proxy in your website so that you call your aspx/php/jsp page, then the page call Facebook, then the page gives you the answer in the proper format (pass-through is proxy-page is in the same domain, JSONP if not)

Comment: Yeah that makes more sense. I was thinking of using secondary php file to retrieve the json data but it was bugging me to know what the issue could be. I also read some articles saying the "invalid label" error cause due to data error in datatype but I was thinking that if the page details call works why won't the page feed work the same way. :( 
Nevertheless Thanks for your help. I really appreciate your work and interest to help me. :)

Comment: I've tried querying the https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php... thing through ASP.NET, but I get an html page from facebook saying to update my browser !!!

Comment: thank u so much, u saved my time and life... :))) plus 1 @AdrianSalazar

Comment: JSON link doesn't seem to work. Says page not available.

Comment: Yeah, JSON seems to have stopped working in just the last month. :(

Comment: Is there a way to get the image of each post as well? The JSON I get only includes message, create_time, id... no image data at all.

Comment: @Adrian Salazar - I need to pull the reviews from a page and it requires an access token which worked fine after generating from Graph API Explorer. The problem is it doesn't exist by an hour long. How can I get the access token for longer time or is there any way to get it permanently and how to do it? I am new to this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Richendrakumarravi  you have to upgrade your token with a request for a long-lived access token. See this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

Comment: Thanks Adrian for this, I read the link u sent, it says Use the user token, your app ID and app secret to make the following call from your server to Facebook's servers.How can i get the app secret? I have the short-lived user token with me, and I didn't a particular steps to do that. Can u find a link which probably says the detailed steps I need to do that so that I can get the Reviews from a FB page and use it in my site?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `&callback=?` from your URL. You have a result handler as part of your function. You don't need a callback.

This *should* give you the result you are looking for, but it appears that Facebook is blocking jsfiddle via an .htaccess policy.

Comment: I have tried it without the callback thing and it just sends an ajax request which strangely returns an empty response. 
and as far as I'm concerned facebook isn't blocking js fiddle cause I have seen a lots of fiddles containing facebook api demonstration. In fact I have created one for you http://jsfiddle.net/33e4M/
As you can see it works fine with the page details json data but as soon as I implement the same thing with page feed it fails and sends me and empty response

Comment: When I run your code as written, there is an `Unexpected token` error due to the callback. Removing `&callback=?` changes the error to "XMLHttpRequest cannot load ... Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed" Your other fiddle is using a different endpoint, which can have different access rules. This gives me the idea that Facebook is crippling this endpoint.

Comment: It won't solve anything because facebook doesn't allow CORS or JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to like the page, and before doing that, i have opened my browser network console. Then when i hit like button, i inspected the network calls, and could figure out the page ID easily.