# how to display jsonp data using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

JQUERY

```
  $.getJSON("https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=397319800348866&format=json&callback=?", function(data) {
    $('#targetDiv').text(data.entries.content);
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="targetDiv"></div>
```

FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/QmvwN/

I tried using above codes.but i'm unable get the result .can you help me to archive this ?

Comment: What errors do you see? What is the value of data? in your call back function? is there a data.text? what is the value for that variable?

Comment: i have updated the code .can you see it again ?

Comment: The response from that url isn't jsonp its regular json

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=397319800348866&format=json  I tried using above url but didn't get any result

Comment: i want to get the facebook post content using json ?

Comment: If this is an open API (i.e. the server accepts cross domain requests), then you don't need JSONP ... try to omit the `&callback=?` part from the request URL

Comment: I am not sure if your callback method is even getting called. Looks like there is some error and it doesnt go into the success method at all.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=397319800348866&format=json i used this code and tried but didn't get any result

Comment: can anyone check it with the fiddle?

Comment: I did check with the fiddle you posted. I changed the code as below and got an error. YOu might want to check out the details of the error `var jqxhr = $.getJSON("https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=397319800348866&format=json&callback=?", function() {
  alert("success");
})
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });`

Comment: Seems like the server does neither send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` nor return a JSONP response. I'm afraid, you're lost then

Comment: and i get into the error loop even after removing the callback,.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926659/get-facebook-page-feed-as-json-with-jquery Seems like you can only use the Facebook Graph API here

Comment: is there any way to do this using any language ?

Comment: Yes , register an new app on a verified facebook account, use a https server to serve content using a endpoint that supports POST requests , allow app to access your account and you are good to go... or do it serverside.