# how do I get json or jsonp from facebook page wall without mime error in chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, jsonp

I've seen posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926659/get-facebook-page-feed-as-json-with-jquery) that show you can get a `JSON` of the wall of a public Facebook page.
But they don't give a working example. I've tried to get it with `$.ajax` and `jsonp` but I get a mime error in Chrome and a different error in Safari and yet another different error in FireFox. What did I miss?

I've created a jsFiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/PrimeLens/x9sNK/) which logs the console, the code is below

```
 $.ajax({
      url: 'https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=54971236771&format=JSON',
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log('Problem with call to get list of articles\n',errorThrown);
      },
      success: function (data) {
           console.log('call success, data is\n', data);
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crossdomain JSON requests are forbidden in current browsers. JSON requests look like:

```
{ foo: 'bar' }
```

And the file you get is pure JSON that is forbidden in all current browsers.
But JSONP is allowed. JSONP looks like:

```
mycallback({ foo: 'bar' });
```

When your url looks like `https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=54971236771&format=JSON` the result is JSON.

To get JSONP you need to use facebook API url and you need to get a special facebook API token from facebook:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/54971236771/feed?access_token=YOUR-TOKEN-GOES-HERE
```

And the actual URL will be something like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/54971236771/feed?access_token=YOUR-TOKEN-GOES-HERE&callback=jQuery110208932981239631772_1401824402598&_=1401824402599
```

The whole code is below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/54971236771/feed?access_token=YOUR-TOKEN-GOES-HERE',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Problem with call to get list of articles\n', errorThrown);
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('call success, data is\n', data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively from using the graph API you can proxy your request through something else like googles feed API:

```
<script>
  function jsapi_loaded(){
    google.load("feeds", "1");

    function initialize() {
      var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(
        "https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=54971236771"
      );
      feed.setNumEntries(10);
      feed.load(function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
          console.log(result);
        }
      });
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
  }
</script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?callback=jsapi_loaded" async></script>
```

Comment: another great answer. but I awarded the green check mark to keiv because he answered first