# Accessing a public Facebook feed without logging in

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, client-side

I am working on a seemingly simple Facebook integration to allow my client (a local restaurant) to display their daily specials on their website. To make this work properly I need to sort through their posts, find the most recent post that has a certain string of characters (to distinguish from other posts they make), and display the post on the webpage. I know how to do this part but I am having trouble getting the data in the first place.

My question: How do I access the data for this Facebook page's posts? This needs to work

- Without logging into Facebook
- Preferably client-side

I would also like to use the JSON from the Graph API but I need an access token according to all the research I have done so far which would force me to go server-side. The Facebook social plugins are not specific enough to do what I want. Any help using the Graph API or another method to retrieve the page's posts is very much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11926757/2151050

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get public page statuses using Facebook Graph API without Access Token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633234/get-public-page-statuses-using-facebook-graph-api-without-access-token)